# Laravel 5 Select popular images

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 tables. The names of the tables are `likes` and `images`.

The `likes` table has the following columns:

1. `id`
2. `image_Id`

The `images` table has the following column:

1. `id`

How do I sort by the number of likes?

Comment: Are you inserting a new row for each new like or do you have a counter that increase with each like for a given image?

Comment: Try this query :
$this->model->leftJoin('Images', 'Images.ID', '=', 'Likes.image_Id')
  ->selectRaw('Images.*, count(Likes.ID) as LikesCount')
  ->groupBy('Images.ID')
  ->get();

Comment: Thank you so much @Maraboc :)